# Trying to create a keydown event for a certain character to highlight a specific div on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I am trying to work out how I can highlight a certain div depending on a keydown event on my keyboard for my webpage. Would be awesome if someone could help me out. Cheers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for you information I have been searching this topic for the last 2 days and found nothing I can interpret clearly, I understand what you're saying but it isn't the case here

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery, the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ob31cmx/) will help.

HTML

```
<div id='test'>Hello world</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.new {
    border:4px solid red !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown',function() {
    if(e.which == 65 || e.which == 66) {  # 65 and 66 are ASCII for a and b in small caps
       $('#test').addClass('new');
    }
  });
  $(document).on('keyup',function() {
    $('#test').removeClass('new');
  });
})
```

Comment: how would I implement jquery, is it like linking to a css file?

Comment: yes its similar, you can write `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` in the body section of your HTML to include it

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work the border just stays black?

Comment: did you try the isfiddle link attached to the answer ?

Comment: yeah for some reason I cant apply it to my web page

Comment: where do you put the javascript?

Comment: you can put it at the end of the body. like `<script> "insert my code here" </script>`

Comment: working now is there anyway it can be manipulated so that it only highlight if a certain key is pressed, can it process multiple keys at once?

Comment: edited my answer, yes it will process multiple keys as long as you use the OR (||) condition.

Comment: this is perfect, lastly how can i manipulate it so 3 keys are assigned to 3 different elements and can light up individually or simultaneously through keydown events?

Comment: inside the if condition, you can simply use $('#id') to select other attributes and use the addClass to highlight them. this [link](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) explains the jQuery selectors. Also could you mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this should work

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">Text</div>
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
   background:green;
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
   if(e.key == '<key here>') mydiv.classList.add('highlight')
})
```

tested working on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u9z68arp/

Comment: thanks for the edit... `addEventListener` is correct

Comment: that hasnt seem to work unfortunately

Comment: see the fiddle, in order for this to work you should focus the "result" window. for short - try clicking on the "text" div and then "e" (lowercase) on your keyboard... it works